# JS: In IE11, string method endsWith() is not working

Tags: javascript, browser, internet-explorer-11

When I tried `this.form.name.endsWith("$END$")` in IE11, getting following error.

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'endsWith'
```

In Chrome, its working fine. Is there any alternative string method in IE11

Comment: `String.prototype.endsWith = "".endsWith || function(s){return !this.split(s).pop();};`

Comment: for future reference ... check MDN documentation - it will tell you if a modern javascript method is compatible with a Neanderthal browser

Answer (score 8):

You may use the polyfill instead

```
if (!String.prototype.endsWith) {
    String.prototype.endsWith = function(search, this_len) {
        if (this_len === undefined || this_len > this.length) {
            this_len = this.length;
        }
        return this.substring(this_len - search.length, this_len) === search;
    };
}
```

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith

Comment: Your link is dead

Answer (score 2):

In IE11 there is no endsWith implemented. You will have to use a polyfill like the one from [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith)

```
if (!String.prototype.endsWith) {
  String.prototype.endsWith = function(searchString, position) {
      var subjectString = this.toString();
      if (typeof position !== 'number' || !isFinite(position) || Math.floor(position) !== position || position > subjectString.length) {
        position = subjectString.length;
      }
      position -= searchString.length;
      var lastIndex = subjectString.indexOf(searchString, position);
      return lastIndex !== -1 && lastIndex === position;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As laid out [here](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-String.prototype_methods_String.prototype.endsWith_a_href=_https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith_title=_MDN_documentation_img_src=_../mdn.png_alt=_MDN_(Mozilla_Development_Network)_logo_width=_15_height=_13_/_/a_nbsp;) and on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith#Browser_compatibility), IE11 does not support `String.endsWith`. You can either use a polyfill - which adds support for endsWith onto the String object - or use existing JavaScript functions, for instance [`String.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) or [`RegExp.test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test):

```
this.form.name.match(/\$END\$$\)
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer a shim cdn as I don't need to worry about another developer breaking the js.
For Wordpress, use this.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'polyfill', 'https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js' , false, '2.0.0', true);
```